# How to change style of radio and checkbox input

Tags: html, css

I have a website where I'm trying to change the background color of the dot of a radio button. Right now it seems to be transparent so it gets the color of whatever the background is. I tried using CSS and setting `"background: white;"` for example, however this has no effect in the browser. Any ideas of cool tricks to use to achieve this?

Same question stands for checkbox as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zequb/7/edit)**

[image: Custom radio and checkbox using css]

This technique uses the `label` element bound to hidden `input` elements, that receiving a `:checked` state will change the apperance of the `:before` pseudo element:

```css
/* COMMON RADIO AND CHECKBOX STYLES  */
input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox]{
  /* Hide original inputs */
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
input[type=radio] + label:before,
input[type=checkbox] + label:before{
  height:12px;
  width:12px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  content: " ";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border:1px solid #777;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
  background:gold;
}

/* CUSTOM RADIO AND CHECKBOX STYLES */
input[type=radio] + label:before{
  border-radius:50%;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before{
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r1"><label for="r1">Radio 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r2"><label for="r2">Radio 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1"><label for="c1">Check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="c2" id="c2"><label for="c2">check 2</label>
```

Comment: That is a great trick.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 10):

It's been well stablished that you cannot change every detail on browser generated controls. For example the color of the arrow on a select dropdown, or the dot of a radio, etc...

You can create your custom controls, use some library like JQuery UI, or.... maybe play around a little with css.

Here's an experiment to fake a colored dot on a radio, using `:before` pseudo element:

http://jsfiddle.net/bvtngh57/

```
input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: looks cool, sadly isn't working on FF

Comment: *Unexpectedly* pseudo-elements are applicable to `<input>` elements on Webkit-based web browsers.

Comment: @HashemQolami Thankfully this has been fixed recently. Pseudo element don't work with inputs on webkit anymore.

Comment: How cool it is when the given PSD has same radio btn :D

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method for styling the non-label elements of checkboxes and radio buttons with CSS is to essentially replace them with images that represent their current state (unchecked, checked, etc).

See this article by Ryan Seddon: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

Answer (score 1):

The browser itself handles the look of radio buttons and checkboxes, as well as dropdown/selects. You can however hide the radio buttons, replace them with images, and then modify your radio/check value using jQuery. Font Awesome (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) has some cool icons that you can use for this.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k1ebqxmt/2/)

```
<div>
    Radio 1 - 
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" value="1" />
    <span class="red fa fa-circle-o"></span>
</div>
<div>
    Radio 2 - 
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" value="2" />
    <span class="blue fa fa-circle-o"></span>
</div>

$('span.fa').on('click', function() {
    $('span.fa').removeClass('fa fa-dot-circle-o').addClass('fa fa-circle-o');
    $(this).removeClass('fa-circle-o').addClass('fa-dot-circle-o');

    //Check corresponding hidden radio
    $(this).prev('input.radio').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, all of them involve to get rid of the DOM styles since it's impossible to do it without these "tricks". Here's a sample by [Chris Coyier](http://www.wufoo.com/guides/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/) (just read the page, skip step 1 and simply prepare teh images and CSS)

```
/*
    Hide the original radios and checkboxes
    (but still accessible)

    :not(#foo) > is a rule filter to block browsers
                 that don't support that selector from
                 applying rules they shouldn't

*/
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio'],
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] {

    /* Hide the input, but have it still be clickable */
    opacity: 0;

    float: left;
    width: 18px;
}

li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio'] + label,
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    margin: 0;
    clear: none;

    /* Left padding makes room for image */
    padding: 5px 0 4px 24px;

    /* Make look clickable because they are */
    cursor: pointer;

    background: url(off.png) left center no-repeat;
}

/*
    Change from unchecked to checked graphic
*/
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='radio']:checked + label {
    background-image: url(radio.png);
}
li:not(#foo) > fieldset > div > span > input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
    background-image: url(check.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style ionic radio buttons using css alone. Check the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sreekanthjayan/0d9vj86k/

```
     <div>
          <ion-radio class="radio radio-inline radio-gray" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'A'">iOS</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio class="radio radio-inline radio-teal" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'B'">Android</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio class="radio radio-inline radio-blue" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'C'">Windows Phone</ion-radio>
     </div>


.radio .radio-icon {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.radio .radio-icon:before {
  content: "" !important;
  border: 2px solid black !important;
  width: 24px !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.radio .radio-icon:after {
  content: "" !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 20px !important;
  top: 22px !important;
  background: black !important;
  width: 12px !important;
  height: 12px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  transition: -webkit-transform .28s cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.000, 1.650);
  transition: transform .28s cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.000, 1.650);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.radio.item-radio > input[type=radio]:checked ~ .radio-icon:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.radio .item-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.radio.item-radio > input[type=radio]:checked ~ .item-content {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.radio-inline.item {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.radio-blue .radio-icon:after {
  background: #2196F3 !important;
}

.radio-blue .radio-icon:before {
  border-color: #2196F3 !important;
}

.radio-teal .radio-icon:after {
  background: #009688 !important;
}

.radio-teal .radio-icon:before {
  border-color: #009688 !important;
}

.radio-gray .radio-icon:after {
  background: #B6B6B6 !important;
}

.radio-gray .radio-icon:before {
  border-color: #B6B6B6 !important;
}
```