# On click change radio background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Radio button i have

For yes:

```
html+='<input type="radio" id="engyes'+val.id+'" name="eradios['+val.id+']" value="'+val.id+'" data-for="yes" onclick="changeinother(this.id);" class="form-control">';
```

For no :

```
<input type="radio" id="engno'+val.id+'" name="eradios['+val.id+']" value="0" data-for="no" onclick="changeinother(this.id);" class="form-control">';
```

On click change radio background color for yes Green and For no Red

script what i am using to change color

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeinother(radioid)
  {
  var curr=$('#'+radioid).attr('data-for');
  if(curr=='no'){
     $('input[type=radio]:checked').css('background-color','red');
  }
  }
</script>
```

> I tried this but its not working with my code what i am doing wrong
>   here can anyone please tell ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25793973/2465787  check this.

Comment: Can't be done with a standard radio button.

Comment: I saw that link but not able to understand that how can i implement that code with my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can not set background color to the plain html radio input, you can use [Custom Radiobutton](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/6jt8h/

```
<div id= "genre">
What do you bust a move to?
<br>
<br>
<form name="music" method="post" action="">
<p>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('b')">Blues
<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('r')">Rock
<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('p')">Pop
<br>
</form>
</div>

window.changeColour = function(value)
{
alert(value);
var color = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
switch(value)
{
    case 'b':
        color = "#FF0000";
    break;
    case 'r':
        color = "#0000FF";
    break;
    case 'p':
        color = "#FF00FF";
    break;
}
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Comment: read question carefully. op want to change radio back-ground color.

Comment: @AmitKumar Sorry, your link will be useful for the question I think!

Comment: Prabaharan Rajendran@ want to change radio backfround color

Comment: @Sneha Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793716/how-to-change-style-of-radio-and-checkbox-input

Comment: I saw that link but not able to understand that how can i implement that code with my problem